# og:image for facebook image into DNN header

Tags: dotnetnuke, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph, rdfa

I am currently using a DNN template to create a website. I need to insert a `og:image` for the Facebook image. Here is the code I am using:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.palmbeachsoftware.com/Portals/0/PBSD_BuildingThumbnail.jpg"/>
```

Do I place this piece of code inside of a module? And if so where?

Comment: I assume DNN = DotNetNuke (I added the tag). I also corrected the code (you had used the wrong quotation marks for the `property` attribute).

Comment: Great thanks! When I place the code into my header of my DNN website and test on Facebook nothing is happening. The image is in the folder it is pulling from, I tested it by placing it into a module and the image came up. @unor

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to the "HEADER" setting within the Page Settings of your homepage.

You'll find the Page settings in the Control Panel when you are logged in with Administrative or Edit rights.

Comment: Great thanks! When I place the code into my header of my DNN website and test on Facebook nothing is happening. The image is in the folder it is pulling from, I tested it by placing it into a module and the image came up. @ChrisHammond

Comment: What should that code do? (haven't looked into it before) just cause the image to load when someone tries to share the URL to that page?